# How to access scoped MAUI class instance from other classes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, maui

How can I access the scoped instance of the following. I want to initiate the connection on startup and keep it during app life time.

```
        AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);

    builder.Services.AddScoped(services => {
        var baseUri = new Uri("http://10.124.2.49:5000");
        var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(baseUri);
        return new ScanItem.ScanItemClient(channel);
    });
```

How do I access the new instance of ScanItem.ScanItemClient from any other class. Also when this connection fails how can you integrate a try catch block in this scope?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I'll try to help.
I would create an additional wrapper in the form of new classes that will configure your service inside.

Example:

```
//In this class, you can add any additional logic and use it as a kind of decorator

public class Auth0Client
    {
        //Your real service. 
        private readonly OidcClient oidcClient;

        public Auth0Client(Auth0ClientOptions options)
        {
            oidcClient = new OidcClient(new OidcClientOptions
            {
                Authority = options.Authority,
                ClientId = options.ClientId,
                ClientSecret = options.ClientSecret,
                Scope = options.Scope,
                RedirectUri = options.RedirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = options.PostLogoutRedirectUri,
                Policy = options.Policy,
                Browser = options.Browser
            });
        }

        public IdentityModel.OidcClient.Browser.IBrowser Browser
        {
            get
            {
                return oidcClient.Options.Browser;
            }
            set
            {
                oidcClient.Options.Browser = value;
            }
        }

        public async Task<LoginResult> LoginAsync()
        {
            return await oidcClient.LoginAsync();
        }

        public async Task<LogoutResult> LogoutAsync(string identityToken)
        {
            LogoutResult logoutResult = await oidcClient.LogoutAsync(new LogoutRequest { IdTokenHint = identityToken });
            return logoutResult;
        }
    }


public class Auth0ClientOptions
    {
        public Auth0ClientOptions()
        {
            Browser = new WebBrowserAuthenticator();
        }

        public string Authority { get; set; }

        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        public string ClientSecret { get; set; }

        public string RedirectUri { get; set; }

        public string PostLogoutRedirectUri { get; set; }

        public string Scope { get; set; }

        public Policy Policy { get; set; }
        public IdentityModel.OidcClient.Browser.IBrowser Browser { get; set; }
    }

public class WebBrowserAuthenticator : IdentityModel.OidcClient.Browser.IBrowser
    {
        public async Task<BrowserResult> InvokeAsync(BrowserOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            try
            {
                WebAuthenticatorResult result = await WebAuthenticator.Default.AuthenticateAsync(
                    new Uri(options.StartUrl),
                    new Uri(options.EndUrl));

                var url = new RequestUrl(options.EndUrl)
                    .Create(new Parameters(result.Properties));

                return new BrowserResult
                {
                    Response = url,
                    ResultType = BrowserResultType.Success
                };
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                return new BrowserResult
                {
                    ResultType = BrowserResultType.UserCancel,
                    ErrorDescription = "Login canceled by the user."
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

Configure services

```
 builder.Services.AddScoped(new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions()
            {
                Authority = config.GetRequiredSection("IdentityServer:Authority").Value,
                ClientId = config.GetRequiredSection("IdentityServer:ClientId").Value,
                ClientSecret = config.GetRequiredSection("IdentityServer:ClientSecret").Value,
                Scope = config.GetRequiredSection("IdentityServer:Scope").Value,
                RedirectUri = config.GetRequiredSection("IdentityServer:RedirectUri").Value,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = config.GetRequiredSection("IdentityServer:PostLogoutRedirectUri").Value,
                Policy = new IdentityModel.OidcClient.Policy()
                {
                    Discovery = new IdentityModel.Client.DiscoveryPolicy()
                    {
                        RequireHttps = config.GetRequiredSection("IdentityServer").GetValue<bool>("RequireHttps")
                    }
                }
            }));
```

Using the service

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {       
        private readonly Auth0Client auth0Client;

        public MainPage(Auth0Client client)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            auth0Client = client;    
        }

        private async void OnLoginClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var loginResult = await auth0Client.LoginAsync();                  
        }

        private async void OnLogoutClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var logoutResult = await auth0Client.LogoutAsync("");          
        }
```

I also recommend using secrets.json to store settings(URI and etc). There is a video on YouTube on how to connect them to the Maui project. The video is called:
".Net MAUI & Xamarin Forms getting settings from secrets.json or appsettings.json"

And most importantly, it will be easier for you to implement try-catch blocks in a wrapper

If you will inject the service directly into the page constructor, do not forget to specify dependencies for it too

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<MainPage>();
```